# Problema con le parole femminili e maschili

Tags: nouns

Io ancora ho problemi a capire o ricordare se certe parole sono di genere maschile o femminile.

Non sono riuscito a trovare un sito per verificare le parole; se esiste,  sarò molto felice se me lo segnalate.

Comment: Vuoi verificare il genere di singole parole o apprendere una regola? Le singole parole si verificano su un qualsiasi dizionario (in rete, per esempio, il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/) o il [De Mauro](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/)); mentre di regole complete non ce ne sono (a parte alcune generali, per cui spesso – ma non sempre – le parole in *-a* sono femminili, quelle in *-o* maschili etc.).

Comment: Puoi trovare un elenco di dizionari nella [nostra pagina di risorse](http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/122/what-good-reference-works-on-italian-are-available-online).

Comment: Grazie, prendere l'esempio,  io scelgo la parola: condizióne

, però se non so (?) il plurale è condizioni oppure condizione, non lo vedo nel dizionario

Comment: Probabile duplicato di http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/7190/how-can-a-beginner-assign-masculine-and-feminine-gender-to-nouns-in-the-italian/7191?s=1|0.1425#7191

Comment: @Farzad64:  Se guardi per esempio in [questo dizionario](http://www.wordreference.com/definizione/condizione), vedi che appare "s.f.", quindi è un sostantivo femminile, e appare anche il plurale, "condizioni".

Comment: Il problema, in effetti, è con le parole che finiscono in -e al singolare, che possono essere maschili o femminili. Bicchiere, ad es., è maschile, chiave è femminile. La parola che proponi (condizione, senza accento) rientra in una categoria che ha una regola: le parole che finiscono in -ione, infatti,  di solito sono femminili singolari.

Comment: @Charo giusto, e detto che sia femminile o maschile, ma non c'è scritto i plurale,  soprattutto se è una eccezione, non posso indovinare, solo lo devo aver sentito

Comment: @Farzad64: Credo che in WordReference siano scritti tutti i plurali.

Comment: @Farzad64, se per te è un problema fare il plurale di una parole in “-zione”, forse la tua conoscenza dell'italiano è meno progredita di quanto pensi.